# How to call static method of a class using c# dll in powerbuilder

Tags: c#, dll, powerbuilder

i have a class which is static and the it has one method which is also static. Now i'm trying to call this method from powerbuilder 12.5.2. When i run the program it gives me error i.e.
"Name not found calling external object function test at line 18 in open event of object w_main." How do I call this method from powerbuilder. I cant use Main method as i have to return an object and as far i know Main method can return int of void.

This is code of my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ProgId("ConsoleApplication1.CallWebService")]
    public class CallWebService
    {
        public static ServiceReference1.DataResult callService(string         
        programId, string loginName, string [] arr)
        {
            try
            {
                string [] test = new string [1] ;
                test[0] = "Yes";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\test.txt", test);
                ServiceReference1.ESSServiceClient reService = new 
                ServiceReference1.ESSServiceClient();
                ServiceReference1.DataPara para = new 
                ServiceReference1.DataPara();
                para.AppAsset = arr;
                ServiceReference1.DataResult ss = new 
                ServiceReference1.DataResult();
                ss = reService.WSRes(programId, loginName, para);
                return ss;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is code of powerbuilder :

```
String msg,arr[]
int li_providerType,li_rtn

oleobject lole_docx
dataresult res


TRY
    any var
    lole_docx = create oleobject
    res = create dataresult
    li_rtn =     lole_docx.ConnectToNewObject("ConsoleApplication1.CallWebService")
    IF li_rtn <> 0 then
            MessageBox( "Error", "Error Loading DLL")
            destroy lole_docx
    ELSE
        arr[1] = "A-Z000001,1"
        res = lole_docx.callService("CM-WA-0001","naphas",arr)
        destroy lole_docx
    END IF

CATCH(RuntimeError er)
    MessageBox( "Error", er.getmessage())
END TRY
```

Comment: Are you using PB Classic or .Net?  "dataresult" is an invalid data type in Classic

Comment: Did you remember to register ConsoleApplication1.CallWebService program in Windows & have all runtime libraries in place for it? If yes, did the ConnectToNewObject function have a successful return code? Since you are connecting as an OLE server PB Classic should be be able to connect without a problem. If you are getting the error on 'test' I'm guessing you made at least one call work. Not so sure about dataresult return type same thing Matt mentioned that concerns me. Maybe start with a simple return value like integer or string to start. Then switch to more complex return when working.

Comment: How to call it in PB? Well you must be developing this for your PB team and you don't know how to use PB. Understandable. Possibly create a barebones response window with button, open the window in your application object open event and put your code behind the clicked of button. Easy peasy. You're on the right track- simplify get it to work, then add complexity back in. For a first time PB question- yours shows some effort which is appreciated- most first PB questions are essentially- can you do it for me? So plus one on the question good job.

Comment: I am guessing the console app was written using .NET - if you don't need the string array just use a string. PB starts arrays at position one, I think .NET starts like other OO languages at index zero. Another potential problem area to remove (at first) if possible.